# Write step_definitions in Sublime Text 2

Tags: cucumber, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then type `Scenario` or `Feature` or `Given` to get auto complete lines for these, to quickly type a `.feature` file.

I am looking for similar kind of plugin to write `step_definitions`.

I have already searched google, but all I found is how to jump to `step_definitons` from `.feature` file

I am on `WIN 8`, using `ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]` on `Sublime Text 2`

Comment: Sharing with @JustinKo may be he can answer.

Comment: how to jump to step_definitons from .feature file?